# Why doesn't Guice from TestNG delivery recognize @javax.inject.Inject while Guice from com.google.inject package does?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, guice, testng

I'm trying Guice. I made a simple example which is very similar to the example in the [Guice Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted) manual.

But it didn't work for some time and said:

> Could not find a suitable constructor
>   in mypack.ServiceUser. Classes must
>   have either one (and only one)
>   constructor annotated with @Inject or
>   a zero-argument constructor that is
>   not private.   at
>   mypack.ServiceUser.class(ServiceUser.java:14)
>   while locating mypack.ServiceUser

The problem was in imports. I attached both Google Guice and TestNG to the project. And I imported classes from `org.testng.guice` package. But annotation `Inject` was imported from the `javax.inject` package. After I changed that import to `org.testng.guice.Inject` my program began working.

But after that I played with imports a little more. And I changed all `org.testng` imports to `com.google.inject`. The program still worked. After that I went back to the `@Inject` annotation and changed its import to `javax.inject.Inject` (as it was in my very first broken version). And the program worked even after that.

I checked ones again: Guice from TestNG packages doesn't work with `javax.inject.Inject` while Guice from google packages (`com.google.inject`) works normally with it.

Why is it so weird?

p.s. I use last versions of both Guice and TestNG (guice-3.0-rc1 and testng-5.14.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: @Guice is still a work in progress and being designed on the mailing-list as we speak, so it's still experimental.

Also, you are using undocumented packages that are reserved for TestNG's internal use (org.testng.guice).

I pushed a new version just today, you can download it at http://testng.org/beta

Note that this new version no longer has org.testng.guice, so make sure that whenever you need Guice symbols, you import them from com.google.inject.

Please post on the testng-users mailing-list if you have any more questions/concerns.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for the new version.

Comment: I'm getting the same error while using only com.google.inject and java.inject.Inject.